# Convert a string field to date

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

So, I have  a two fields in my log: `timeLogged`, `timeQueued` all this fields have date format: `2014-06-14 19:41:21+0000`

My question is, how to convert string date value to logstash date? like in @timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this filter

```
filter {
    ruby {
        code => "
            event['timeLogged'] = Time.parse(event['timeLogged'])
            event['timeQueued'] = Time.parse(event['timeQueued'])
        "
    }
}
```

Use the powerful ruby library to do what you need!

Comment: Hi,
It generate an error: `WARN: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper: [Chi Demon] [logstash-2014.06.29] Type [.fr (93.17.128.7)] contains a '.', it is recommended not to include it within a type name`

Comment: Is it a logstash error or elasticsearch error? The logs you provided is worked on me.

Comment: You can try to disable the filter first and try whether it will also produce the elasticsearch error. In your error message it is not the filter problem. So, maybe it is other problem that cause this. Can you provide the full logs and your configuration?

Answer (score 1):

For the sole purpose of converting to @timestamp there is a dedicated date filter

```
 date {
     match => ["timeLogged","YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+SSSS"]
 }
```

Now in your case there are basically two types of fields that might be used so you will have to dig a little, either use a grok filter to copy the values in a generic "log_date" field, or trying to see if the date filter can take several arguments like one of thoses possibilities:

```
 date {
     match => ["timeLogged","YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+SSSS",
               "timeQueued","YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+SSSS" ]
 }
```

OR

```
 date {
     match => ["timeLogged","YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+SSSS"]
     match => ["timeQueued","YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+SSSS"]
 }
```

It is up to you to experiment, I never tried myself ;)

Answer (score 1):

this should suffice

```
date{
    match => [ "timeLogged","ISO8601","YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    target => "timeLogged"
    locale => "en"
    }
```